# getting Could not find the data view in Kibana visualization TSVB

Tags: elasticsearch, devops, kibana, elk

I am getting "could not find the data view" in kibana TSVB visualization sometimes

error printing in kibana logs,

```
[2023-05-04T18:47:46.215+05:30][WARN ][plugins.usageCollection.usage-
collection.usage-counters-service] ResponseError: [usage-
counters:uiCounter:04052023:count:dashboard:render_tsvb_convertable]: version 
conflict, required seqNo [34190], primary term [6]. current document has seqNo 
[34206] and primary term [6]: version_conflict_engine_exception Root causes: 
version_conflict_engine_exception: [usage-
counters:uiCounter:04052023:count:dashboard:render_tsvb_convertable]: version 
conflict, required seqNo [34190], primary term [6]. current document has seqNo 
[34206] and primary term [6] at KibanaTransport.request (/finapp/kibana-
8.7.0/node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/Transport.js:479:27) at 
runMicrotasks (<anonymous>) at processTicksAndRejections 
(node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) at KibanaTransport.request 
(/finapp/kibana-8.7.0/node_modules/@kbn/core-elasticsearch-client-server-
internal/src/create_transport.js:51:16) at ClientTraced.UpdateApi [as update] 
(/finapp/kibana-
8.7.0/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/api/api/update.js:50:12)
```

Current setup: `filebeat->logstash->elasticsearch->kibana version: 8.7.0`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zav0S.png)

please help in analyzing and fixing this.

---